# Iterate over lists of form fields in a template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am attempting to group my form fields so that I can iterate over each group separately within my template:

```
# app/forms.py
from django import forms

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.FieldClass(label="Field 1")
    field2 = forms.FieldClass(label="Field 2")
    field3 = forms.FieldClass(label="Field 3")
    field4 = forms.FieldClass(label="Field 4")
    group1 = [field1, field2]
    group2 = [field3, field4]
```

```
# app/templates/app/formTemplate.html
<form method="POST">
    <div>
        {% for field in form.group1 %}
            <p style="display: block">
                {{ field.label }}
                <span style="float: right">
                    {{ field }}
                </span>
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% for field in form.group2 %}
            <p style="display: block">
                {{ field.label }}
                <span style="float: right">
                    {{ field }}
                </span>
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</form>
```

As far as I am aware, this ought to display as:

```
Field 1    INPUT FIELD 1 HERE
Field 2    INPUT FIELD 2 HERE

Field 3    INPUT FIELD 3 HERE
Field 4    INPUT FIELD 4 HERE
```

But what I get instead is:

```
Field 1    <django.forms.fields.CharField object at ...>
Field 2    <django.forms.fields.CharField object at ...>

Field 3    <django.forms.fields.CharField object at ...>
Field 4    <django.forms.fields.CharField object at ...>
```

Additionally, if I use `{% for field in form %}` instead of `{% for field in form.groupX %}` it will render as expected (except that it will have all fields in both divs).

Does anyone know why this won't work?

I have scoured the docs and API and cannot find any mention of this or any indication that it shouldn't work.

I have also tried using `{{ field.field }}`, `{{ field.widget }}` and `{{ field.widget.render }}` all to no avail.

Of course I am also open to alternative suggestions for grouping form fields in a concise manner.

Comment: Because Django's metaclass logic to turn the fields into renderable objects does not work if these are "hidden" in lists.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That makes sense - how do I access that metaclass logic from the field object?

Comment: I don't want to change your way of doing things but things like this should be done with JS - i know its a pain in the ass but altering your form class can lead to some unpredictable behaviour. I usually just get the form as {{ form.as_table }} and then adjust it in JS to my needs its much more flexible than jinja.

Comment: That's all well and good but my JS is far from great...
Additionally the form I am rendering will be used to create several separate models, hence why I can't just use a CreateView class-based view.